# Is it possible to remove a header and footer from a single page? (word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word

I've searched for it, I have to remove headers and footers in single sections of my document, not just the first page. How can i do it easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible to remove a header and footer from a single page?

Use a **Section Break**.

> You can use section breaks to change the layout or formatting of a page or pages in your document. For example, you can lay out part of a single-column page as two columns. You can separate the chapters in your document so that the page numbering for each chapter begins at 1.
>
> **You can also create a different header or footer for a section of your document**.

Source [Insert a section break](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c)